# parameterized sorts

Tags: z3, smt

How can I access the values of parameterized sorts?

For instance, if I have the following declarations:

```
(declare-sort Pair 2)
(declare-const x (Pair Int Int))
```

How do I access the first element in the pair which `x` represents?

Comment: You should post some code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a parametric record with two selectors `first` and `second` for accessing its field.

Here is [an example](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/gc8):

```
(declare-datatypes (T1 T2) ((Pair (mk-pair (first T1) (second T2)))))
(declare-const p1 (Pair Bool Int))
(declare-const p2 (Pair Int Int))
(assert (first p1))
(assert (> (first p2) 2))
(assert (= (second p1) (second p2)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

There is also a comprehensive introduction on [algebraic datatypes](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h27) in Z3 SMT guide.

Comment: Thank you!  Are there any limitations on the fields?  I would like to make one of the fields an Array.  I wasn't able to find detailed information on this in the Z3 guide, although it was helpful.

Comment: I don't think there is any limitation. You should try it out and see what you get.